# Cannot query Hive view which relies on UDTF

Tags: function, view, hive

I've created a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INT, SCORE INT, NAME STRING);
```

and inserted several records. I would like to perform a top-k query, returning the top records for each ID, sorted by SCORE.

I'm using the each_top_k() UDF from the Hivemall library as documented here: https://hivemall.incubator.apache.org/userguide/misc/topk.html

```
SELECT EACH_TOP_K(1, ID, SCORE, ID, NAME) AS (RANK, SCORE, ID, NAME) FROM (
SELECT * FROM TEST
CLUSTER BY ID
) T;
```

which successfully returns the top SCORE for each ID. However, I then create a view as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS SELECT EACH_TOP_K(1, ID, SCORE, ID, NAME) AS (RANK, SCORE, ID, NAME) FROM (
SELECT * FROM TEST
CLUSTER BY ID
) T;
```

and it executes successfully. However, then a simple

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_VIEW;
```

returns the following error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException View
>   test_view is corresponding to UDTF, rather than a SelectOperator.
>   (state=42000,code=40000)

I can't find any mention of this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suppose that Hive has problems to infer the data type for each field for your udtf at runtime. This should solve it, try put a query on top of your query, something like

```
CREATE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS 
select cast(rank as long) as rank, cast(score as double) as score, cast(id as string) as id, cast(name as string) as name from (
SELECT EACH_TOP_K(1, ID, SCORE, ID, NAME) AS (RANK, SCORE, ID, NAME) FROM (
SELECT * FROM TEST
CLUSTER BY ID
) T ) t2;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it. Had to do with data types being generated by the function not aligning with the original fields.